# How to change the lua version NLua uses?

Tags: c#, .net, lua, version, nlua

I want to use Lua 4.0.1  instead of 5.2, because I have to parse 4.0.1  scripts.
The syntax of the generic for loop has been changed since then (with no backwards compatibility).

If this is not possible, are there any alternatives to NLua that support this?

Comment: How did the for loop syntax change? I don't see much of a difference by looking at [4.0](https://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#for%20statement) manual.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko Lua 4.0, and 5.0 in legacy, support `for namelist in exp do block end`, where the expression is a table. Lua 5.0/5.1 and later use iterator functions (`pairs/ipairs`).

Comment: It may be easier to convert the script before executing them if that's the only difference.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko How would you do that automatically? It has to work without any manual editing.

Comment: You'd need to replace `in exp do` with `in ipairs(exp) do`, which shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: So string manipulation, oh...
Thanks, I'll try that.